# How to re render MKMapView to update overlay according to new coordinates

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocation

I've written this function to add overlay at Loading View and its working perfectly.

How can I use this function or any other method to update overlay according to new coordinates I pass on a button click.

I'm passing an array of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` of coordinates.

```
 func drawpolyline(loclist: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>) {
   //  if let overlays = self.mainMapView?.overlays {
   //      self.mainMapView.removeOverlays(overlays)
   //  }

   if (loclist != nil && loclist.count > 1) {
        let startmark = loclist.first
        let cord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (startmark?.latitude)!, longitude: (startmark?.longitude)!)

        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: loclist, count: loclist.count)
        print(polyline.pointCount)
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.02
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.02

        let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: cord1, span: mapSpan)
        // let adjustedRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = [self.mainMapView regionThatFits:viewRegion]

        if (mainMapView != nil) {
          self.mainMapView.delegate = self
          self.mainMapView.add(polyline)
          self.mainMapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true);
          // self.mainMapView.addAnnotation(mapAnnotation);
        }
    } else {
        configureMap()
    }
}


//function of MKMapViewDelegate for making overlays
//Function to give polyline color and width etc.
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    //Return an `MKPolylineRenderer` for the `MKPolyline` in the `MKMapViewDelegate`s method
     if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
        let testlineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        testlineRenderer.strokeColor = .blue
        testlineRenderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        return testlineRenderer
    }

    fatalError("Something wrong...")
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have a button set up, and linked with IBAction.
You need to call the `drawpolyline` function from the button action giving the new coordinates in the same format as you have previously when calling it on launch but for your new location.

If you don't understand, maybe provide some more information on how you call the `drawpolyline` function on launch, I assume in the `viewDidLoad`.

If you don't know how to call a button use

```
@IBAction func showListPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // call drawpolyline function here with new coordinates
}
```

Comment: I am calling this function in ViewDeidLoad to draw polyline on launch. 

But when I call this function on button click,  the mainMapView object is nil every time.